# Syncing Person accounts

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, person-accounts

when the MC connector is installed and when there are Person Accounts on the Salesforce org, we have to sync the Contacts AND the Accounts objects in SFMC, because most of the time, we also need Accounts for some "joins" in SQL query.

However, it seems that Accounts are also counted as "Contacts" in All Contacts in Contact Builder, whereas most of Contacts and Accounts are the same "person".
As SFMC billing is also based on the number of Contacts, are these Accounts also counted as billable Contacts? If yes, is there a way to handle this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Accounts are not counted as billable contacts: see [help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_definition_and_count_determination.htm&type=5)

Salesforce Contacts, Salesforce Leads and Salesforce Users are counted as billable contacts in Marketing Cloud when using MC Connect.

Please note that a Contact in Marketing Cloud is a sendable record with a unique ContactKey identifier.